# Jquery event firing order

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the function call that contains an ajax request fire off before the append?

```
$("#range").on("click", function(){
    $("#control").empty().append(.....); //why does this get executed after?
    var data = 'something';
    some_function_with_ajax(data);  
 }


function some_function_with_ajax(data){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {data: data},
        success: function(resp){
          // seems the append actually happens here  
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't fire after it.  The browser will not perform a redraw until it gets a turn in the processing cycle.  Your script is adding the data to the DOM, but it is executing the ajax before the redraw has a chance to do it's business.

Comment: @Taplar Will a kitten die if I use `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Have you set `async: false` globally for all AJAX requests?

Comment: @Kisaragi eh, no?  Is it actually that critical for the markup to render before the ajax starts?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no, it needs to be async

Comment: That's a good thing :) Making a sync request was the first thing I could think of to cause this. I think Taplar is correct then. Why is it so imperative for the `append()` to happen first? There will be a delay of ~25ms or so, at most, between calls.

Comment: Its not, I wasn't aware this behavior is expected